# Padding-top solution not working for bootstrap fixed-top navbar problem

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

My navbar is overlapping my content. All similar questions seems to have been solved by either (1) padding-top or (2) if padding-top is applied, make sure the custom.css is loaded after the bootstrap css. I have done both. I am using Django, and I know it is loading my custom.css because the background color is applied. I put my navbar in `head` when it didn't work the first time, it was in `body` before, but I was thinking the padding-top might be applied to that as well. Anyways, please help make it work! Here is my code:

base.html

---

```
<head>
{% load static %}
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/custom.css' %}">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'main:index' %}">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'main:index' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</head>



<body>

    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

---

custom.css

---

```
body {
    background-color: #242627;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

a { color: inherit; }
```

---

Comment: look at `sticky-top`class in BS4 :  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/position/#sticky-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of padding top you should go about giving it `margin-bottom` instead. You are trying to keep the navbar and the top and rest of the content below it. So give the navbar a margin-bottom to keep the other content down. Also dont give it to the body! make a custom class like `.custom` and add it to the navbar.

Comment: I put the navbar back in the body wrapped it in a div and gave it its own class and did the margin-bottom, and it worked - thanks! Don't if that was exactly what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the `padding-top` to your `body`, you're adding it to the `nav` since that is in the body too. If you have a `div` below the `nav` in the chain of code, add the padding to that:

```
    <div class="nav">
      <!-- nav code -->
    </div>
    <div class="next-content"> <!-- APPLY PADDING-TOP TO THIS -->
      <!-- code -->
    </div>
```

Comment: I suck at html, but what do you mean that it is in the body too? It was contained within the head tags.

Comment: The content of the page is inside the `<body>` element, so when you apply something to `body`, it just applies it to the entire page (all content inside the body), not that individual element.

Comment: So what you are saying that even though I have put my navbar inside the `<head>` element (like in my code above), it will still adopt the styling I give the `body`?

Comment: Why is your `<nav>` being put in the `<head>` (I don't think I've ever noticed that before)?

Comment: Didn't notice their `<nav>` was in the `<head>` actually, but if that's the case, then it wouldn't fall under the `<body>` and the answer about using `margin` on it would be the solution

Comment: I have no idea! Don't know what I am "allowed" to put there. I think my first step in problem solving was what your point has been - I wrote that I put it in the `head` after having it in the body originally but was thinking that if I apply something to the `body` and my navbar is in the `body`the same will be applied to both the navbar and the other content I actually wanted it applied to.